# TSQL Technique for attribute evaluation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 20 columns.  The first is my primary key.  The remaining columns are attributes about the primary key.   I need to evaluate each column on a row by row basis.   If a attribute column has a value other than null, then do some further processing.

The way I am familiar with doing this in TSQL would be a while to bump through the rows, capture the values from the columns, evaluate the values for further processing.

Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: Do you evaluate all columns (i.e. any column is not null?) or only certain columns.   If column 1 is null and column 2 isn't, do you process it?   Need some more details to help answer this

Comment: I have to inspect each column, if it's anything other than null, send it on for further processing.   If it is null, I can skip it.

Comment: What does "further" processing entail?

Comment: @Sparky, maybe you were talking about dependencies?   The columns are all independent values.

Comment: Maybe you can do the whole thing with a single UPDATE statement, depending on what kind of "further processing" you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could unpivot the table and filter out things that are not NULL:

```
select pk, col, val
from (select pk, col, val
      from table t
      unpivot (val for col in (attr1, attr2, . . . )) as unpivot
     ) u
where val is not null;
```

This will provide a list of the columns and associated non-NULL values.  Note:  it assumes that the types of the attribute columns are all the same.

Comment: This looks like it will do the trick very nicely.   Much better than a bunch of IF statements for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to first define if any column actually has a null value. For that you could use something like the following;

```
Select DATALENGTH(null,'Attr1','Attr2') // Add all the colums. This will return null. All of the columns must be the same type.
```

This will return null. Let's say that you have a while loop(you could use Cursor as well but they are considered slower compared to while loops) that checks each row with against the results of this statement and when you find the result to be null then you could actually check which column is null. This should speed up the process a little bit.

Also, this one looks pretty easy about finding the rows that has null values: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14864/test-if-any-fields-are-null

Answer (score 0):

```
select PK from table where col1 is not null or col2 is not null or col3 is not null
```

etc.